# The string is missing the terminator: ". powershell jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins, groovy

have a strange problem trying to automate a powershell line.

On my powershell it works but under Jenkins pipeline it always says the following error :

```
The string is missing the terminator: ".
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

My code line :

```
powershell $mybranch = (get-content F:\software\branchname) -replace '.*?/'; new-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "\\myserver\sw\software\rs\2020-RC1_$branchname"; copy-item -path "E:\Temp\2020-07-22_1.1.1-RC1_$branchname.zip" -destination "\\myserver\sw\software\rs\2020-RC1_$branchname\"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's trailing backslash before double quote in `… -destination "\\myserver\sw\software\rs\2020-RC1_$branchname\"`. Double it.

### Example:

```
powershell -noprofile dir "packages\"
```

> ```
> The string is missing the terminator: ".
>     + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
> ```

```
powershell -noprofile dir "packages\\"
```

> ```
>     Directory: D:\bat\packages
>
>
> Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
> ----                 -------------         ------ ----
> d-----        01.06.2020     10:41                com.company.sft
> ```